# Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type in c#

Tags: c#

I have a Chat class. In chat class the is a ChatMessage List, and Inside the ChatMessage class there is a ChatHistory Class. I requirement is to get the ChatHistory Collection. When I try like below mentioned code it shows, **"Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type"**    Please give any suggestion to fix this, I have referred many answers but it is not meet my requirement

```
foreach (var textMessage in store.Chat.Where(s => s.ChatMessage.Where(a => a.ChatHistory.Count > 0 && a.IsDeleted == false)).ToList())
```

**Chat.cs**

```
List<ChatMessage> ChatMessage = new List<ChatMessage>();
```

**ChatMessage.cs**

```
List<ChatHistory> ChatHistory = new List<ChatHistory>();
```

**ChatHistory.cs**

```
public string ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: try this `var textMessage in store.Chat.Where(s => s.ChatMessage.Any(a => a.ChatHistory.Count > 0 && a.IsDeleted == false)).ToList()`

Comment: Are you operating on eg. EntityFramework? or pure lists?

Comment: @ershoaib, When I try your code, but ChatHistory Inside property is not accessed inside the foreach loop. I want to access the ChatHistory property like this, `textMessage.ChatHistory.Where(a => a.ID)`

Comment: @x39, I am using EntityFramework

Comment: could you please add your classes?

Comment: @ershoaib, Please see my updated code

Comment: try this => `foreach (var textMessage in store.Chat.Where(s => s.ChatMessage.Any(a => a.ChatHistory.Count > 0 && a.IsDeleted == false)).SelectMany(x => x.ChatMessage).ToList())
            {
                var a = textMessage.ChatHistory.Where(b => b.ID == "");
            }`

Comment: @ershoaib, Thanks its now working without error. You can add this to answer. I will accept your answer

Comment: @suresh, can i add this ans answer to your question? then u mark as accepted and vote up also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all here its hard to (or can't) use `Where` inside `Where` on single variable instead of this you can use `Any` inside `Where` it may gives you your output.

And by using `SelectMany` you can get all your `ChatHistory`.

```
foreach (var textMessage in store.Chat.Where(s => s.ChatMessage.Any(a => a.ChatHistory.Count > 0 && a.IsDeleted == false)).SelectMany(x => x.ChatMessage).ToList())
{
    var chatHistory = textMessage.ChatHistory.Where(b => b.ID == "SomeId");
}
```

Comment: "First of all you can't use Where inside Where". Not quite true, you just need to use a different variable inside the nested where clause. e.g. List<List<int>> a = new List<List<int>>{ new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 },new List<int>{ 1, 1, 0 },new List<int>{4,6}}; var b = a.Where(i=>i.Count>2 && i.Where(j=>j>2).Any());

Comment: @CooncilWorker, yes you are right but cant use where on same variable. need a different variable btw I don't mean to say you can't use `where` inside `where` all the time but its grammatical and typing mistake from me,  now answer updated

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
s.ChatMessage.Where(a => a.ChatHistory.Count > 0 && a.IsDeleted == false)
```

will return an IEnumerable but we need a bool.

You probably want to use .Any() instead of .Where()

```
foreach (
    var textMessage in store.Chat.Where(
        s => s.ChatMessage.Any(
            a => a.ChatHistory.Count > 0 && a.IsDeleted == false
        )
    ).ToList()
)
```